# How to get paths in getStaticPaths with locales in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, next.js, strapi

I'm using Strapi as a CMS, where I query for slugs, and I would like to have statically generated pages using getStaticPaths and getStaticProps in Next.js.

As I need to work with multiple locales, I have to map through the locales and get paths for each "Announcements" I'm getting from my query.

The error message I'm getting is:

`Error: A required parameter (slug) was not provided as a string in getStaticPaths for /updates/announcements/[slug]`

This is my getStaticPaths:

```js
export async function getStaticPaths({ locales }: any) {
  const paths = await (
    await Promise.all(
      locales.map(async (locale: any) => {
        const { data } = await client.query({
          query: gql`
            query Announcements {
              announcements(locale: "${locale}") {
                data {
                  attributes {
                    slug
                    locale
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          `,
        });
        return {
          announcements: data.announcements.data,
          locale,
        };
      })
    )
  ).reduce((acc, item) => {
    item.announcements.map((p: any) => {
      acc.push({
        params: {
          slug:
            p.attributes.slug === "/" ? false : p.attributes.slug.split("/"),
        },
        locale: p.attributes.locale,
      });
      return p;
    });
    return acc;
  }, []);

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  };
}
```

If I console.log(paths) I get the following in the terminal:

```
[
  { params: { slug: [Array] }, locale: 'en' },
  { params: { slug: [Array] }, locale: 'en' },
  { params: { slug: [Array] }, locale: 'en' },
  { params: { slug: [Array] }, locale: 'da' },
  { params: { slug: [Array] }, locale: 'sv' },
  { params: { slug: [Array] }, locale: 'nb' }
]
```

I might think that Next.js don't want the slug to be an array, but I'm not entirely sure. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As the error message says, `slug` should be a string. You're passing it as an array as you can see when logging `paths`, because you're using [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split). I'm not sure why you want to split the string, but maybe you're looking for something like `slug.split('/')[1]` instead?

Comment: Also FYI, your line `p.attributes.slug === "/" ? false : p.attributes.slug.split("/")` can also end up with `slug` being `false`, which probably also wouldn't work well with Next.js. Can you give more details on what the slugs from strapi look like and what you're trying to do with this ternary?

Comment: @RobinMétral I was following this article, and he is mentioning that it is required by next.js. 

https://www.mckenna.codes/blog/nextjs-localized-routes-tutorial

Comment: I tried `slug.split('/')[1]` but it gives me the same error message.

Comment: An example of a slug: "restore-a-rejected-or-archived-creditor-invoice"

Comment: So, it turned out that I don't need the .split, if I do a normal dynamic route.

Comment: If a slug looks like `restore-a-rejected-or-archived-creditor-invoice` then the ternary definitely won't do anything (because it's not equal to `/` and doesn't contain a `/`). Did removing it answer your question, then?

Comment: Yes it did work, and thank you for letting me that way!

Comment: No worries. Do you want me to add a quick note about slugs as strings as an answer or do you want to write it yourself?

Comment: If you have the time for it, it is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You page uses [dynamic routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes) named (`/updates/announcements/[slug]`), therefore the param `slug` is required in `paths`.

From the [Next.js `getStaticPaths` documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-paths):

> The `paths` key determines which paths will be pre-rendered. For example, suppose that you have a page that uses Dynamic Routes named `pages/posts/[id].js`. If you export `getStaticPaths` from this page and return the following for `paths`:
>
> ```js
> return {
>  paths: [
>    { params: { id: '1' }},
>    {
>      params: { id: '2' },
>      // with i18n configured the locale for the path can be returned as well
>      locale: "en",
>    },
>  ],
>  fallback: ...
> }
> ```
>
> Then, Next.js will statically generate `/posts/1` and `/posts/2` during `next build` using the page component in `pages/posts/[id].js`.

The `slug` param can only be a `string` since it's used to generate routes. As you found when logging `paths`, you were trying to pass `slug: [Array]`.

The problem in the question's code snippet is this expression to assign a `slug`:

```js
// ...
params: {
  slug: p.attributes.slug === "/" ? false : p.attributes.slug.split("/"), // 
},
// ...
```

This expression will either assign `false` (boolean) or an array of substrings (see the docs for [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)).

In this case, as confirmed in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74428143/how-to-get-paths-in-getstaticpaths-with-locales-in-next-js#comment131391046_74428143) above, simply passing the slug as a string solves the issue.

The confusion likely came from following a tutorial that uses an [optional catch-all route](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#optional-catch-all-routes) (`pages/[[...slug]]`) instead of regular dynamic routes (`pages/[slug]`) ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74428143/how-to-get-paths-in-getstaticpaths-with-locales-in-next-js#comment131390633_74428143)).

From the [Next.js `getStaticPaths` documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-paths) again:

> - If the page name is `pages/posts/[postId]/[commentId]`, then params should contain `postId` and `commentId`.
> - If the page name uses catch-all routes like `pages/[...slug]`, then params should contain `slug` (which is an array). If this array is `['hello', 'world']`, then Next.js will statically generate the page at `/hello/world`.
> - If the page uses an optional catch-all route, use `null`, `[]`, `undefined` or `false` to render the root-most route. For example, if you supply `slug: false` for `pages/[[...slug]]`, Next.js will statically generate the page `/`.